# Apache forces URL to contain a backslash at the end of URL

Tags: apache, http-status-code-301, errordocument

I had just finished defining error pages using the `ErrorDocument` in httpd.conf. After restarting the server, I noticed that when I entered the address of a directory (not a file) like http://www.example.com/adirectory, Apache gave a "301 Moved Permenantly" error. Removing the ErrorDocument didn't do anything either. THe only way to access these URLs is to include a / at the end of the URL, like http://www.example.com/adirectory/ How can I allow URLs to be displayed without the / at the end. Thanks, San.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Apache rules.

Specifically .htaccess RewriteRule with a regular expression to end URL with a /

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess file, and the only rewrite rules in my httpd.conf file are to force www. :

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Rewrite the request to end with a / if one is not found